# Toggle script not working on prettyPhoto

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, prettyphoto

I'm running a Wordpress site with the Woocommerce plugin.

If you take a look [here](http://www.crystalight.com.sg/products/business-portfolios/business-portfolio-4/)... it's a product's page with expandable details such as the "Business Portfolio Contents" toggle button on the side.

However if you look at the [Catalogue page](http://www.crystalight.com.sg/product-category/calendars-diaries/portfolios/), hover over the product and click "Quick View". It shows the same contents but the "Business Portfolio Contents" toggle button is no longer working right.

The lightbox used is prettyPhoto and I believe the toggle button's js file is shortcodes.elements.js . I noticed that if I clicked on the Quick View before the page is completely loaded, it would actually work properly, so I'm guessing a script that's being run later on is causing the problem?

I'm not very familiar with js so a little explanation would help!

Comment: Your toggle is working properly ,what is wrong?

Comment: @PratikJoshi it's not working in the "Quick View" mode in the Catalogue page